# What's pit? A pit in a bed

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

how can I say that there is some hidden 'pit'(?) in my bed?
I want to express that the 'pit' is under the level of the flat bed surface. How can I say that? For my understanding 'pit' is something I dig with a shovel. I would like to know a word I can use not only referring to bed or furniture but just to be able to say that there is some 'blabla' (valley?,LOL, but not about nature) within a flat surface, so it goes flat, flat, flat then deeper for a while and then flat again. 
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're describing is a storage compartment which, in terms of [furniture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinetry#Compartments), would typically be referred to as a "[hidden compartment](https://www.thisiswhyimbroke.com/hidden-storage-compartment-bed/)" or "[secret compartment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_compartment)" or, depending on the way it's accessed, a "secret drawer."

Those terms wouldn't be relevant to all flat surfaces, but the following nouns are some generic options for describing changes in a surface:

- dip
- divot
- dent
- depression
- hollow

A thesaurus would provide additional options. You could use them interchangeably in a sentence like:

> The surface was flat except for a **dip** in the center.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like I've found the word, so it's " hollow"

Definition of hollow (Entry 1 of 4)
1 : an unfilled space : CAVITY, HOLE
in the hollow of a tree
2 : a depressed or low part of a surface
especially : a small valley or basin
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hollow

Comment: You could say that there's a low spot in your mattress, or a gap in the bed frame (for example, there's a missing slat).